# Protractor: Compare two element for equality

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I have this list of elements

```
list = element.all(by.css(....));
```

One of them has an specific attribute

```
specific = list.element(by.css('[active]');
```

Now I would like to check if this `specific` element is the first

```
expect(list.get(0)).toBe(specific)
```

However this doesn't work (it doesn't match). Any suggestion how to compare elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the value of `active` attribute and see if it is not null:

```
expect(list.first().getAttribute("active")).not.toBeNull();
```

---

You *cannot though directly compare elements*, but, you can [compare `id`s](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getId) or `outerHTML` attribute values of elements:

```
expect(list.first().getId()).toEqual(specific.id());
expect(list.first().getAttribute("outerHTML")).toEqual(specific.getAttribute("outerHTML"));
```

Comment: thnx a lot, that will do. Just curious, is it possible to compare elements?